# Javascript ES6 map does not allow same argument as ES6 forEach?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

```
commonChampions.forEach(([championA, championB]) => {....}) // Valid

commonChampions.map(([championA, championB]) => {...})  // Invalid
```

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token `[`

Anyone know why this is the case? This seems very odd and counter intuitive to me.

Actual code:

```
var championCompareList = commonChampions.map( ([championA, championB]) => {
  var championCompare = compareChampionStats(championA.stats, championB.stats);
  compareValue += championCompare.compare;
  ({ id: championA.id, result: championCompare });
});
```

Is it possible that my Node environment is not set up properly to handle ES6? Currently I am using webstorm and I have set the language to ECMAScript 6 when I inspect the .map function the ECMAScript map function is from ECMAScript 5 js file

Comment: Assuming your code includes the missing `)` at the end of each line, both lines work fine.

Comment: var championCompareList = commonChampions.map( ([championA, championB]) => {
        var championCompare = compareChampionStats(championA.stats, championB.stats);
        compareValue += championCompare.compare;
        ({
            id: championA.id,
            result: championCompare
        });
    });

Comment: You forgot the `return` keyword when returning the object. I still can’t reproduce this error.

Comment: In ES6 you dont need to do a return http://es6-features.org/#ExpressionBodies

Comment: In this case you need the `return`, because you have a _block_ as the body of the arrow function, not an _expression_.

Comment: @Michael concise bodies are an *option*, but if you don't use them you still need the `return`.

Comment: ok thanks for the knowledge guys im still new to JS, nonetheless still doesnt work :(

Comment: The *championCompareList* code block you have provided, works.

Comment: _“Is it possible that my Node environment is not set up properly to handle ES6?”_ That’s probably it.

Comment: Ok thanks @Xufox for the help appreciate it

Comment: This should definitely work. Usually webpack comes along Babel, check if you have the right presets in your `.babelrc` file. Array concatenation is the ES6 feature that may thow you an error.

Comment: ES6 shouldn't be a factor re: `map` method. It is an ES5 array method, and nothing about it changed between specs

Comment: @felguerez Huh? The code is using arrow functions and argument destructuring, both of which were introduced in ES6. Thus, this is ES6 code.

Comment: @Xufox, yes arrow functions are ES6, but `map` is an ES5 method. in the body of the question OP notes: "I have set the language to ECMAScript 6 when I inspect the .map function the ECMAScript map function is from ECMAScript 5 js file". I wanted to point out that the language version shouldn't impact how the the callback function is evaluated. `Array.map` did not change with the introduction of arrow functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I helped @Michael with this offline. Answering here in case others find this post when encountering the same problem.)

I suspect your Node version is out of date. Type `node --version` at the command line and compare the version number to the current version found at https://nodejs.org.